# git: Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged - I don't want to push "27 different" commits and want to uncommit them and keep the local commit?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 27 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: To make the remote look like your local you need to force push (`git push --force-with-lease`) Note, your title says `origin/master` but your question says `origin/feature-sprint-33`. Normally you probably wouldn't want to force push something to `origin/master`.

Comment: Are you using a very old version of Git? Just curious.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't throw anything away, just pull before pushing as the hint from Git suggests. You might get a nicer result by saying `git pull --rebase`. If that works, then just `git push` and you're all set.

Comment: I also want to uncommit those 27 different commits, will this ( "git pull --rebase" ) work?

Comment: Why do you want to discard 27 commits worth of work

Comment: It would be very unusual to discard 27 commits that exist _on the remote_. The remote isn't going to want to let you do that. As you've been told, you could `force` this to happen, but it is considered a bad idea.